# Batch script to delete files older than X days (based on creation date, not modified date)

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

On a windows machine (win 7 or Win server 2008 R2) I have a batch script that copies some .config files to a backup folder. 
I want to write another script that deletes the backup files created a week earlier.

There are plenty of suggestions on how to use `FORFILES` (as example):

```
FORFILES /P "D:\Configs_Backup" /M *.config /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @file"
```

But this command uses the "modified" timestamp, while I need to use the creation date.

Without installing any third party program, is it possible via command console to achieve this?

Comment: You may use `DIR /TC`, but date parsing may be required.

Comment: This may not be the best way, but you could force the original script to create the file fresh so that the `modified date` is new. I just personally hate doing any sort of string parsing with batch files.

Comment: @Gray: yes maybe not optimal, but actually yours is not a bad idea in my context. +1 for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this, look at the output and remove the `echo`, if it looks good:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a XDay=7
CALL :DateToJDN "%DATE%" JDNToday
FOR /r "D:\Configs_Backup" %%a IN (*.config) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1,4*" %%b IN ('dir /tc "%%~a"^|findstr "^[0-9]"') DO (
        CALL :DateToJDN "%%b" filedate
        SET /a diffdays=JDNToday-filedate
        IF !diffdays! gtr %XDay% ECHO DEL /F /Q "%%~a"
        )
    )
GOTO :eof

:DateToJDN "DD mm/dd/yyyy" jdn=
setlocal
set date=%~1
set /A yy=%date:~-4%, mm=1%date:~-10,2% %% 100, dd=1%date:~-7,2% %% 100
set /A a=mm-14, jdn=(1461*(yy+4800+a/12))/4+(367*(mm-2-12*(a/12)))/12-(3*((yy+4900+a/12)/100))/4+dd-32075
endlocal & set %2=%jdn%
exit /B
```

Note: this works only for `AM/PM` time format.

Comment: I made some tests and it works fine. My local time format has 24 hours (European time) and not AM/PM format. However giving old and new files, the batch is able to select only the older than 7 days ones. Were you referring to something else?

Comment: for your time format change `"tokens=1,4*"`  to  `"tokens=1,3*"`. This works here.

Comment: If you modify this `IF !diffdays! gtr %XDay%`, the batch can also select many other times and ranges, please look at `if /?`  at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps - Keep the 5 *.config files (skip=5) with the most recent creation date
Test it on sample files.

```
@echo off
pushd "d:\folder"
   del file2.tmp 2>nul
   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.config /b /a-d ') do call :getcreationdate "%%~fa"
   sort /r <file2.tmp >file.tmp
   for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,*" %%a in (file.tmp) do del "%%~b"
   del file.tmp file2.tmp 
popd
pause
goto :EOF

 :getcreationdate
 set "file=%~1"
 set "file=%file:\=\\%"
 WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%file%" get creationdate | find "." >file.tmp
 for /f %%b in (file.tmp) do set dt=%%b
 set dt=%dt:~0,8%_%dt:~8,6%
 del file.tmp
 >>file2.tmp echo %dt% "%~1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I stumbled across it and it helped. I ended up going the route hinted at by @Gray as a comment and changed my .bat copy script to this so that it would update the modified date when copying rather than trying to solve it in the clean up script.

```
copy %1 %2 /y
copy /b %2+,, %2
```

https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch