# Delete all files older than 1 day / 24hours using creation date?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, delete-file

I want to delete all files older than 1 day / 24 hours using a timed task in the OS and a batch file.

This is needed for a simple backup mechanic I've implemented, that saves a certain file every hour and I don't want to delete old files manually.

I already implemented the following batch code, which successfully create a backup every hour. However, the delete portion of the code doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why?

PS: I'm using Win7 x64.

Code:

```
rem Get day of week
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET /a count=0
FOR /F "skip=1" %%D IN ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek') DO (
if "!count!" GTR "0" GOTO next
set dow=%%D
SET /a count+=1
)

:next

rem Check if day of week is Saturday or Sunday. If so, goto end of file.
if %dow% == 6 GOTO eof
if %dow% == 7 GOTO eof

rem Set hour
set TIMESTAMP=%TIME:~0,2%"Uhr"

rem Copy file including timestamp
xcopy "SOURCE FOLDER" "TARGET FOLDER\filename_%date%_%TIMESTAMP%.accdb*" /Y

rem Delete files older than 1 day
forfiles -p "TARGET FOLDER (from above)" -s -m *.* /D -1 /C "cmd /c del @path"


:eof
```

**Edit:**

I found the cause of the original problem, it was the UNC paths. Instead of using them I just mapped the path to a drive letter now and deleting works fine now.

However, it deletes all my files now, instead of just the ones older than 1 day.

I suspect that forfiles uses the last modification date instead of the creation date, as the last modification is still on 26th and the creation was like an hour ago...

Is there a way to circumvent that behavior and use the creation date instead?

Alternatively, is there a way to set the modification date to a certain timestamp after copying the file?

Comment: Attention! `forfiles /D` looks for date only, not time. So if you run it shortly after midnight, it may process files that are only 10 minutes old. Just mentioning, because you wrote _older than 1 day / 24 hours_.

Comment: Ah I think I found the reason... Forfiles doesn't support UNC paths apparently -.- Is there an alternative you know? What do write instead of /D ?

Comment: Just a question. Do you exactly need to delete files older than 24h or is it enough to delete files not from the current day? If the second case is an option, delete all files with a date different of today.

Comment: I want to have the last 24 hours backuped, so yeah I need to delete all older than 24h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using the getTimestamp.bat from dbenham: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847&p=27422#p27422

This is the only working batch file I could find that is able to calculate the date of yesterday (potentially any day for that matter).

It is probably the only working one, because all others (and also all of the ones linked in the regarding StackOverflow threads) don't take locale settings into account, so they didn't even start for me.

```
call getTimeStamp -od -1 -f {dd}.{mm}.{yyyy} -r dt

rem Copy file including timestamp
xcopy "\\unc\folder\fileToBackup.accdb" "\\unc\folder\backupedFile_%date%_%TIMESTAMP%.accdb*" /Y

rem Delete yesterdays file
del "\\unc\folder\backupedFile_%dt%_%TIMESTAMP%.accdb*"
```

Comment: How does this take creation date into account, as your question states? Creation date is a timestamp of a file in the filesystem, not part of a filename.

Comment: It does not, I had to use a different approach (see comments of the other answer). I don't think there is any way to take the creation date into account, however, you don't really need it if you timestamp the files you copy in their name

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little "convoluted" but this should do the work

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=\\server\share\somewhere"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
        'robocopy "%folder%" "%folder%" /l /nocopy /is /minage:1 /njh /njs /ndl /ns /nc /fp'
    ) do echo del "%%a"
```

`del` commands are echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

It uses the `robocopy` command to search the required files in the UNC path. So, natively, only for vista and later OS. For XP, the Windows 2003 Resource Kit Tools include a working version of robocopy.

EDITED - One more. Trying to avoid the timestamp on files

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=\\server\share\somewhere"

    for /f "tokens=* skip=24" %%a in (
        'dir /b /a-d /tc /o-d "%folder%"'
    ) do echo del "%folder%\%%a"
```

With a file generated every hour, keep the last 24 and delete the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however, your script has the exact same problem... It seems to use the "last modified" date instead of creation date. Therefore way too many files are deleted.

Comment: I might try a different approach now though. I think if I am able to define a variable storing the date of yesterday (%date% - 1 or something), then I can just delete the file "filename_%yesterday%_%TIMESTAMP%.accdb*" and everything should work fine, as I don't even need the timestamps.

Comment: @daZza, that was the reason for my initial comment asking if it is enough to consider files not from today. You don't even need to get yesterdays day. Having today date, delete every file without the date of today.

Comment: Nope, your idea is not working. There are always two days worth of backups, as I always need the latest 24hours....

Comment: To explain further: On the 01.04.2014 at 11:00 I realize that some errors have occured and can trace the reason back to changes that were made 12 hours before, so on 31.03.2014 at 23:00. If I would use your method, I couldn't restore the backup after only 12 hours have passed, because the files were already deleted,as they are from a different day (31.03. vs 01.04).

Comment: @daZza, please see updated answer. Still trying to have to deal not with the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

`forfiles` does indeed use the *modified* timestamp, not the *created* timestamp, so you cannot use it for what you want.

You might like to check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785216/) which parse the file creation date in a batch script, or if you're willing to use PowerShell then you could try [this script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Delete-files-older-than-x-13b29c09) with the arguments `-CreateTime` option.