# Looping Through a Directory and Extracting Data From The Files Created Today

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, grep, cygwin

I have some *.XML files located in a directory and its subdirectories. These files are increasing from time to time because of the periodic usage of a win batch script that I use for other tasks after extracting the XML files contents .

I know how to loop through all the files and extract the needed data, but what I don't know is how to loop through only the files created today, so that I can extract what I need from them.

Here is what I'm doing to extract the data from all the files:

**1-By Using The "Grep" Tool, to Extract The Files' Contents**

```
grep -r -hi --include="*.XML" "Pattern" > My.Data
```

.

**2-By Looping in The .XML Files, and Combine Them into One File!**

```
For /R %%X in (*.XML) Do @Type "%%X" >> My.Data
```

Yes I know It's a bit weird to use that second command while I have Grep! But actually, I need 99% of each file content, so both ways are almost the same for me .

As for my problem, I think it would be great if somebody can help me to modify one of the commands above, to loop in the xml files created today. But if it's not possible, or there is a better way in someone's mind, please don't hesitate to share it. And by the way, I have Cygwin installed on my system (win7-64)

Thanks so much guys in advance,
I wish to get the right answer from here as usual. - Karim :)

Comment: `for %a in (*.*) do @for /F %d in ("%~Ta") do @if %d equ %date% echo File created today: "%a"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I think the command you're looking for is `forfiles`.  Type `forfiles /?` for full syntax.  To grep only files that were *modified* today, do:</s>

`forfiles /s /m *.xml /d +0 /c "cmd /c grep -hi ^"pattern^" @file >>\path\to\My.Data"`

**Edit:** As Karim pointed out, `forfiles` matches files based on `last modified` date.  He's looking to match files based on `created` date.

---

To get a file's creation date, use `dir /tc` and capture it with a `for` loop like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: get recursive list of XML files
:: note: In US locale, a dir listing has 5 columns:
:: MM/DD/YYYY  HH:MM  AM/PM  size  filename
:: With "tokens=1,4*":
::   %%a captures date
::   %%b is throwaway (capturing file size)
::   %%c captures the filename with spaces

for /f "tokens=1,4*" %%a in ('dir /s /tc *.XML') do (

    rem :: In US locale, %date% is in format "Day-of-week MM/DD/YYYY"
    rem :: If your locale doesn't list date last, see
    rem :: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php
    rem :: for an explanation of string manipulation.

    if "%%a" equ "%date:* =%" (

        rem :: do stuff.
        grep "Pattern" "%%c" >> My.Data

    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Bro for your reply. That's exactly what I was trying to do myself, but then I noticed that my `xml` files, have Creation date completely different than the Modification Date (months or even years in some cases!). That's why I was asking for the creation date of the files Not the Modification date.  
So, Please if there is any idea to modify your command for that purpose, it would be really great. also if there is a better way or other tools to do that, Please let me know... Appreciate Your Help - Karim :)

Comment: I see.  OK, I added a new example that should do what you want.  You might have to tweak it for your locale.  See the comments in the script for details.  Let me know how it goes!

Comment: It Worked!! I knew you're gonna do it because of your first answer, -simple, easy to edit, and most of all, it doesn't affect the rest of the batch functions. FYI, My Batch has about 1500 lines, which Used For tens of other tasks (each Command Depends on the output of the one Before). So, My big problem was to add the right commands for any new tasks, without affecting the batch negatively, by loosing one of my main advantages (adding the new files based on a TimeStamp, of their last modification date). Anyway, your command is perfect, and it's much better than expected - So Grateful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (   (for /r %%a in (*.xml) do (echo(%%~ta_%%~fa)) ^
        |(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('findstr /l /b /c:"%date%"') do (type "%%b")) ^
        |grep -ih "pattern"
    ) > My.Data
```

The code is just a pipe with three commands.

The first `for` loop will iterate over the `*.xml` files in current folder and subfolders (`/r`) and output the date and time of the file (`%%~ta`), an underscore (used as delimiter) and the full name of the file (`%~fa`).

The second `for` loop will filter this list to only get the files with the date of today (this has not been done in the previous step to avoid operations to handle date formats that include day of week), split the record (using the underscore as delimiter) and `type` the content of the file.

The third command is the `grep` that will filter the data.

All the generated content is redirected to the output file.

**edited** Aggg!!! Creation date !!! Whithout using a scripting engine, the only way i see to do it is to process the output of a `dir` command, that is not the more structured source of data.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Temp files needed
    set "tempList=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.list.tmp"
    set "tempData=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.data.tmp"

    rem Retrieve data from system to be able to parse the dir command
    set "colSkip="
    for /f "tokens=1-10" %%a in ('dir /ad ^| findstr /r /c:"> *\.\."') do (
        if not defined colSkip if "%%a"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=1"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%b"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=2"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%c"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=3"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%d"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=4"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%e"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=5"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%f"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=6"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%g"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=7"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%h"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=8"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%i"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=9"
        if not defined colSkip if "%%j"=="<DIR>" set "colSkip=10"
    )
    for /f %%a in (".") do set "drive=%%~da"
    for /f %%d in ("%date%") do set "today=%%d"

    rem Execute a dir command to find the list of files that will be processed
    echo ... Searching files
    > "%tempList%" (
        dir /s /tc /a-d *.xml | findstr /b /r /c:"%date%" /c:" [^ ].*:\\.*"
    ) 

    rem Process the list to find final file names with full path
    echo ... Processing file list
    set "folder="
    > "%tempData%" (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%tempList%") do for /f %%b in ("%%a") do if not "%%b"=="%today%" (
            for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in ("%%a") do set "folder=%drive%%%c"
        ) else for /f "tokens=%colSkip%,*" %%c in ("%%a") do (
            set "file=%%d"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo ...... found: !folder!\!file! > con
            type !folder!\!file!
            endlocal
        )
    )

    rem Extract the final needed data 
    echo .... extracting data
    > "My.Data" (
        grep -ih "pattern" "%tempData%"
    )

    rem Clean temp files    
    del /q "%tempData%" >nul 2>nul 
    del /q "%tempList%" >nul 2>nul 

    exit /b
```

Too much code, but is should work independtly of the date format, day of week or am/pm hours. The first `for` loop will just search the column in the `dir` command output where the file name is located.

With all the necessary previous information, the list of files is retrieved. A recursive `dir` command configured to retrieve the creation date is used to list all the `.xml` files under the current folder and the `findstr` will filter this list to only get files with the today date or the line with the name of the folder. This information is sent to a temporary file (not knowing the volume of the information to retrieve, this method is more stable than a `for /f`)

Now we have a list of folders and files. For each line in the input file (`%%a`), it is determined if the line contains the name of the folder or a file (`%%b`). If it is a folder, its name is retrieved (`%%c`) and stored to later concatenate to the files name. If it is a file, extract the file name (`%%d`) from the rest of the columns, concatenate to the folder name and dump the contents of the file. The output of all the files will be sent to a temporary file that will be later processed to only retrieve the needed information.

Why all this code? It should be locale independent. Only one `dir` command is used to retrieve the full list of files to process. There is one `type` for each file found, but only one `grep` for all the data

Comment: Thanks *MC ND* For your reply.. unfortunately, your code didn't give me any results (Don't know why), but I think your idea in general is really good :) ... I have another idea but I don't know if it's possible. is it possible to use the `Dir` command for that job? I mean something like `For /F %%a in (Dir Command) Do grep/type....` what do you think about that ? - Thanks -

Comment: @KarimAlHousiny, the only difference between a `for /f + dir /s` and a `for /r` to list files is when there are hidden files or the files being iterated are being created/deleted at the same time. Not the case here. The main problem with your indicate approach is that a `grep` command is executed for each file, something i'm trying to avoid. I've tested the posted code and for me it is working, but reading your comment to rojo's answer, it will  not work for you if the modification date (used in this code) is wrong. Is creation date the correct field? Back to the drawing board ....

Comment: @KarimAlHousiny, answer updated. Are you sure you need to do it using the creation date?

Comment: Just curious. I thought the Julian date method was pretty spiffy--and have now seen variations all over the internet and wonder what you see as the drawbacks.

Comment: @sjoy, no drawbacks on julian dates (while I prefer ISO formats), but there are two "problems/drawbacks" with the code you posted. First, in batch files `call` operations are essential and wondeful to organize the code but are SLOW, and there is a call for each file. Second, the reason for the greater part of code in my answer, dir output depends on locale configuration. I'm not even 100% sure my code will work on every imaginable machine/locale (and i decided not to do calcs!) but sorry, your code does not work on my machine (no week day, dd/mm/yyyy date). Dates in batch files are a nightmare

Comment: @MCND Hmm..I did test it and it worked for me. Oh, yes, it returns only the difference between file creation date and "today," so presumably if diff is 0 the file was created today. Anyway, np and I am glad for info about call. Speaking of date calculations, you may enjoy this [link](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-datemath.html)

Comment: @sjoy, Yes, the idea and your code are both correct, but it works for you because the date format in the output of your `dir` command matches the intput to the subroutine, and does not work for me because my locale configuration is different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you all considered this? It will definitely tell you the files that were created today. I'm not sure it's the final answer, but maybe you who have been working on it can build from here. I've had trouble with modification vs. creation date myself, so was interested in looking into it. It's only a slightly modified version of [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785216/batch-script-to-delete-files-older-than-x-days-based-on-creation-date-not-modi).

The correct path needs to be entered in the FOR /r loop.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

    :: Convert today's date to julian format
    CALL :DateToJDN "%DATE%" JDNToday

        FOR /r "PathToXMLfiles" %%a IN (*.xml) DO (
            :: The dir /t:c gets creation date
            FOR /f "tokens=1,4*" %%b IN ('dir /t:c "%%~a"^|findstr "^[0-9]"') DO (
               :: Convert file creation date to julian
               CALL :DateToJDN "%%b" filedate
               SET /a diffdays=JDNToday-filedate
               IF !diffdays! EQU 0 echo created today!
            )
         )
        GOTO :eof

:DateToJDN "DD mm/dd/yyyy" jdn=
REM Convert dates to Julian
    setlocal
    set date=%~1
    set /A yy=%date:~-4%, mm=1%date:~-10,2% %% 100, dd=1%date:~-7,2% %% 100
    set /A a=mm-14, jdn=(1461*(yy+4800+a/12))/4+(367*(mm-2-12*(a/12)))/12-(3*((yy+4900+a/12)/100))/4+dd-32075
    endlocal & set %2=%jdn%
    exit /B
```

BTW, this is for 12-hour clock time. For 24 hour time, change "tokens=1,4*" to "tokens=1,3*".

Comment: Just read rojo's edit. I assume the main difference--besides his is much shorter ;) --is that this one converts to julian date so you are comparing numbers not formatted dates.